# Azure devops pipline: how to add task to PR work item with PS script (az boards work-item)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I am using this code in Azure Devops Pipeline:

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Create workitem task'
      env:
        AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $nameLine= az boards iteration team list --team "DevOpsTesting Team" --timeframe current --project $(System.TeamProject) | findstr "name" 
          $nameOnly= (select-string ":(.*)" -inputobject $nameLine).Matches.Groups[1].Value.Replace(",","").Replace("`"","").Trim()
          az boards work-item create --title "New PR request for version from $(Build.RequestedFor)" --type Task --project $(System.TeamProject) --iteration "$(System.TeamProject)\\$nameOnly" --assigned-to <some_user_email> --fields "Description=$(Build.RequestedFor) want to merge into Main, a PR is open, please test the new exe version and approve. link to download: $(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/artifacts?artifactName=<some_name>&%24format=zip"
      timeoutInMinutes: 5
```

To create a new task, and it is working.
I will like this task to appear in the PR work item - the PR is what triggered the pipeline.

[image]

Is there anyway to do it automatically with a script?
(I know this can be done manually..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do it automatically with a script?

Yes. We can use the Azure DevOps CLI: [az repos pr work-item add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-work-item-add) to add the new work item to Pull Request.

```
az repos pr work-item add --id PRID --work-items WorkItemID
```

From your description, the pipeline is triggered by pull request. You can use the predefined variable: `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` to get the Pull Request ID in Pipeline.

Here is an example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Create workitem task'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $nameLine= az boards iteration team list --team "DevOpsTesting Team" --timeframe current --project $(System.TeamProject) | findstr "name" 
      $nameOnly= (select-string ":(.*)" -inputobject $nameLine).Matches.Groups[1].Value.Replace(",","").Replace("`"","").Trim()
      $workitem =  az boards work-item create --title "New PR request for version from $(Build.RequestedFor)" --type Task --project $(System.TeamProject) --iteration "$(System.TeamProject)\\$nameOnly" --assigned-to <some_user_email> --fields "Description=$(Build.RequestedFor) want to merge into Main, a PR is open, please test the new exe version and approve. link to download: $(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/artifacts?artifactName=<some_name>&%24format=zip"
      $workitemid =  $workitem.id

      az repos pr work-item add --work-items  $workitemid  --id $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
  timeoutInMinutes: 5
```